# How to find specific element within the iframe of electron app?

Tags: c++, winapi, electron, microsoft-ui-automation

I am using the code similar to this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-howto-find-ui-elements#finding-an-element-by-name
for getting specific element within a window and it doesn't work if my element is inside iframe which is inside electron app.

However this changes if I run [insights](https://accessibilityinsights.io/) and manually inspect my electron application (Slack, Teams etc.). After that my code execution finds exact element within the iframe.

EDIT:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    HRESULT hr;
    int ret = 0;
    IUIAutomationElement *pTargetElement = NULL;

    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

    IUIAutomationElement *pRootElement;

    std::string elementName = "Missed";
    CComBSTR temp(elementName.c_str());

    std::string inputWindowTitle = "Microsoft Teams";
    CA2T wt (inputWindowTitle.c_str());
    HWND hwnd = ::FindWindow(NULL, wt);

    IUIAutomation *pAutomation = NULL;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(CUIAutomation), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IUIAutomation), (void **)&pAutomation);
    if (FAILED(hr) || pAutomation == NULL)
    {
        ret = 1;
        goto cleanup;
    }

    PROPERTYID pPIDProperties[] = {UIA_BoundingRectanglePropertyId};

    IUIAutomationCondition *pCondition;
    VARIANT varProperty;
    VariantInit(&varProperty);
    varProperty.vt = VT_BSTR;
    varProperty.bstrVal = temp;

    SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
    SetFocus(hwnd);
    SetActiveWindow(hwnd);
    
    if (SUCCEEDED(pAutomation->ElementFromHandle(hwnd, &pRootElement)))
    {
        if (SUCCEEDED(pAutomation->CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, varProperty, &pCondition)))
        {
            if (SUCCEEDED(pRootElement->FindFirst(TreeScope_Descendants, pCondition, &pTargetElement)))
            {

                if (pTargetElement != NULL)
                {
                    BSTR nn;
                    hr = pTargetElement->get_CurrentName(&nn);
                    wprintf(L">> ELEMENT FOUND (%s)! ", nn);

                } else {
                    wprintf(L">> ELEMENT IS NULL");
                    goto cleanup;
                }
            } else {
                wprintf(L">> ELEMENT NOT FOUND! ");
                goto cleanup;
            }
        } else {
            wprintf(L">> SOMETHING WRONG WITH CONDITION ");
            goto cleanup;
        }
    }
    else {
        wprintf(L">> NO WINDOW ");
        goto cleanup;
    }
cleanup:
    if (pTargetElement != NULL)
        pTargetElement->Release();

    if (pAutomation != NULL)
        pAutomation->Release();

    CoUninitialize();
    return ret;
}
```

How should I approach this correctly and why after Accessibility Insights interaction my element can be found, is there some caching behind this?

Comment: Maybe there's a bug in your code. We cannot see your code. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: @IInspectable I just added the code to my description. Thanks

Comment: if I run electron app with `--force-renderer-accessibility` it works great...